# Problema ao mudar cores do menu com bootstrap-less 3.3.7

Tags: bootstrap-3, less

Pessoal estou fazendo um site com `HTML5` e `bootstrap-less`tudo funciona normalmente porem precisava alterar algumas cores no menu `navbar` e sei que posso fazer isso através das `variables.less` dentro desse arquivo eu navego até a parte dos menus onde copio todo o código relacionado ao menu que que quero editar e colo no meu arquivo `.less` porem o mesmo não funciona não quero ter que usar `!important` para alterar o menu sendo que sei que posso fazer isso mexendo somente nas variáveis no `less` que vem no bootsrap esse é o código `less` do menu 
LESS:

```
@navbar-default-color:             #fff;
@navbar-default-bg:                #f8f8f8;
@navbar-default-border:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);

//* Navbar links*/
@navbar-default-link-color:                #fff;
@navbar-default-link-hover-color:          #fff;
@navbar-default-link-hover-bg:             transparent;
@navbar-default-link-active-color:         #fff;
@navbar-default-link-active-bg:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);
@navbar-default-link-disabled-color:       #fff;
@navbar-default-link-disabled-bg:          transparent;

/* Navbar brand label*/
@navbar-default-brand-color:               @navbar-default-link-color;
@navbar-default-brand-hover-color:         darken(@navbar-default-brand-color, 10%);
@navbar-default-brand-hover-bg:            transparent;

/* Navbar toggle*/
@navbar-default-toggle-hover-bg:           #fff;
@navbar-default-toggle-icon-bar-bg:        #fff;
@navbar-default-toggle-border-color:       #fff;
```

mesmo eu alterando os valores ele não altera em meu site percebam que deixei tudo branco para fazer um teste e no meu site não altera:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse é o meu menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box-menu">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="assets/images/logo-santa-clara-eco.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Santa Clara EcoResort" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline contact-info">
                            <li class="list"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>Rod SP 215 Km 197 - Dourado - SP</a></li>
                            <li class="list"><a href="tel:551633454004"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>+55 (16) 3345 4004</a></li>
                            <li class="list"><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/contato.php"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contato</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <img src="assets/images/logo_top.png" class="img-responsive logos-inline" alt="Tripadvisor L'OCITANE ABR" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
                <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-nav-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/index.php"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/resort.php">resort</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/acomodacoes.php" id="question" >acomodações</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/gastronomia.php">gastronomia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/atividades.php">atividades</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/spa.php">SPA</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/eventos/outdoor-training.php">eventos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/monitora/monitora-clubinho.php">monitoria</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/pacotes/final-de-semana.php">pacotes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/programacao.php">programação</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/contato.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contato <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/localizacao.php">Localização</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline social-networks hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-tripadvisor" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

eu estou importando tudo normal o `css` do `bootstrap` e o `js` juntamente com o `jquery` e estou fazendo o `@import` certinho

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

meu arquivo app.less com o import:

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "app.css";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

imagem das minhas variáveis com as cores que preciso mudar, copiei as variáveis do arquivo `variables.less` e adicionei no meu `app.less` mudei as cores elas aparecem no console porém não sobreescrevem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu arquivo `less` com as alterações de cores (lembrando que isso ai é uma cópia do arquivo `variables.less`)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No Developer Tools do Chrome na parte da direita onde costuma ter os CSS clica no aba `Computer` e da um Inspect onde está a cor errada e confere de onde ele está puxando essa cor. To achando que tem um CSS seu Sobrescrevendo o outro

Comment: @hugocsl vou verificar aqui um instante

Comment: vi aqui amifo e meu color ta assim rgb(51, 51, 51)
;

Comment: @hugocsl eu criei um app.css que é onde fica meu css minificado e tem o app.less que é onde eu crio meu código de estilo por enquanto só criei o menu e ja to com essa dificuldade sabe o que pode ser

Comment: @hugocsl postei o print do console na questão lá

Comment: rgb(51, 51, 51) é igual #333333 que é a primeira cor que aparece no Inspetor, logo sua cor está no bootstrap.css linha 4515. Só que parece que ela afeta outros elementos. De qq forma troca lá pra outra cor e testa se funciona!

Comment: @hugocsl entendi amais ai se eu for ter que reescrever o código do bootstrap é ruim não concorda pois uma vez que eu já tenho as variaveis de less dele não seria necesário eu mudar direto no css do bootstrap tipo se eu inspecionar o elemto minhas alterações que viz via less vai estar lá porem elas não sobrescrevem eu teria que usar o !important e nao queria ter que usar isso

Comment: @hugocsl baixei o bootstrap desse site aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ peguei o less sera que é algum problema nos arquivos sei lá nunca tive esse problema vou colocar um print da pasta do meu bootstrap o variables.less ta meio estranha a pasta e vou colocar um print tbm do console mostrando as cores que setei nas variaveis porque elas estão lá mais nao sobrescrevem as do bootstrap que seria o certo.

Comment: @hugocsl Adicionei no fim do aquivos mais algumas screenshootes

Comment: é super comum customizar o BS, principalmente fazendo override das classes que já vêm no framework. Vc pegou os arquivos no link certo sim, isso não é problema. **Olha se não é a ordem que vc está indexando os links na <head> da página. O seu CSS deve ser o último a ser chamado.**

Comment: @hugocsl cara seguinte estou important meu estilo css aqui <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: esse é do bootstrap e esse aqui é o meu css <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css" /> se eu retirar o estilo do bootstrap minhas alterações funcionam

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70669/discussion-between-hugocsl-and-kirito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kirito confere a ordem de indexação dos CSSs na `<head>` da página que vc vai resolver o seu problema!

Seu CSS que está com as classes que vc quer substituir deve ser o último!

Se ele estiver assim não vai funcionar...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/SEUCSS.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Inverta a ordem deles que vai dar certo. Olhe abaixo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/SEUCSS.css" />
```

[]´s